# How can I make a UIButton enable as a touch when I drag from area outside in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, drag

I am trying to make a UIButton be able to be enabled if I drag my finger from the region outside the button.  It only works right now if I press the button like normal.  I have tried using all of the events, but it doesn't look like it even will respond to any of the drag events.  I have searched everywhere, but I cannot find an answer.  Thanks!

Comment: You want the button to be enabled when user drag in to the button from outside, that means the button is disabled earlier..A disabled button doesnt get any touch events..

Answer (score 1):

You should need to use a selector to `dragEnter` event for a `UIButton`.

```
[your addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDragged:)   
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragEnter];
```

and implement the buttonDragged: method

```
-(void)buttonDragged:(UIButton*) sender{
  //Your logic here
}
```

Comment: So I tried the code and was unable to get it to work.  Here is the code:  
'[topbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(addScoreTop:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];'                          Do you have any suggestions on how to enable the button.  It still seems like it is unresponsive.  I put the code in the viewDidLoad method.  Is this correct?